# How does monetization of opensource app works?

Tags: license-compatibility, commercial, relicensing, project-management

I have a couple of questions regarding making a PRO version of an app.

- If I want to make a PRO version with more features of my already
  existing open-sourced MIT licensed app, what changes should I make to
  the license and code? Should I fork and maintain a private repo with
  different license?
- If I get any contributors to the oss version, since I'll be using
  majority of the oss code, will the contributors who helped on oss
  version become stakeholders? If so, How much and how to share revenue
  among contributors?

For example, how does business model of Octotree browser extension work? (Amazing extension. If you use GitHub, do yourself a favor and use it.) It is Opensource and has FREE and PRO versions.

Any other things & suggestions I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I want to make a PRO version with more features of my already existing open-sourced MIT licensed app, what changes should I make to the license and code? Should I fork and maintain a private repo with different license?

You should maintain at least a separate (private) repository for the code of the PRO features. If this PRO repository needs to contain code from the oss repository depends on the code structure and how the PRO features are integrated into the rest of the code. Any code that is copied from the oss to the PRO repository needs to keep their MIT license statement and copyright notice. This, however, does not prevent you from distributing a binary-only PRO version.

> If I get any contributors to the oss version, since I'll be using majority of the oss code, will the contributors who helped on oss version become stakeholders? If so, How much and how to share revenue among contributors?

The contributors to the oss version are copyright holders to (parts of) the code. As you are using the MIT license, which allows using the contributions in code under a different license, this is not a problem to use the contributions in your PRO version.

The contributors are *not* automatically entitled to a share in the profits you make from a paid version. If and how much of your profits you want to share with your contributors is entirely up to you.